# The initial code is missing from the new Visual Studio version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, structure, workflow

in earlier Visual Studio versions there was always ready-made code when you created a new project. Unfortunately, that doesn't exist anymore. Anyone know how to undo this? It irritates me a lot because this initial code is preserved in many C# tutorials and no longer with me due to the new version. I would really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: What kind of project are you creating? Are you sure this isn't just a matter of the console project template now being very, very small due to top-level statements and implicit using directives?

Comment: When creating a new console app, at the top of the screen is a link to the new console template with the comment `// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information`. Here is the [link](https://aka.ms/new-console-template)